# How can I Include Multiples Tables in my linq to entities eager loading using mvc4 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, eager-loading

I have 6 classes and I try to use `linq` to Entities to get the `SiglaUF` information of the last deeper table (in the view - MVC). The problem is I receive the following error:

**"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."**

The view is like that:

> ```
> >     @model IEnumerable<DiskPizzaDelivery.Models.EnderecoCliente>
> >     @foreach (var item in Model) {
> >          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CEP.Cidade.UF.SiglaUF)
> >     }
> ```

The query that i use:

```
 var cliente = context.Clientes
       .Include(e => e.Enderecos)
       .Include(e1 => e1.Enderecos.Select(cep => cep.CEP))
       .SingleOrDefault();
```

The question is: How Can I improve this query to pre loading (eager loading) "Cidade" and "UF"?

See below the classes:

```
public partial class Cliente
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<EnderecoCliente> Enderecos { get; set; }
    }
public partial class EnderecoCliente
    {
        public int IdEndereco { get; set; }
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public string CEPEndereco { get; set; }
        public string Numero { get; set; }
        public string Complemento { get; set; }
        public string PontoReferencia { get; set; }
        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
        public virtual CEP CEP { get; set; }
    }
public partial class CEP
    {
        public string CodCep { get; set; }
        public string Tipo_Logradouro { get; set; }
        public string Logradouro { get; set; }
        public string Bairro { get; set; }
        public int CodigoUF { get; set; }
        public int CodigoCidade { get; set; }
        public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
    }
public partial class Cidade
    {
        public int CodigoCidade { get; set; }
        public string NomeCidade { get; set; }
        public int CodigoUF { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CEP> CEPs { get; set; }
        public virtual UF UF { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UF> UFs { get; set; }
    }
public partial class UF
    {
        public int CodigoUF { get; set; }
        public string SiglaUF { get; set; }
        public string NomeUF { get; set; }
        public int CodigoCidadeCapital { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Cidade> Cidades { get; set; }
        public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
    }

var cliente = context.Clientes
                .Where(c => c.Email == email)
                .Where(c => c.Senha == senha)
                .Include(e => e.Enderecos)
                .Include(e1 => e1.Enderecos.Select(cep => cep.CEP))
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply include the entire navigation path.

```
 var cliente = context.Clientes
       .Include(e => e.Enderecos)
       .Include(e1 => e1.Enderecos.Select(cep => cep.CEP.Cidade.UF))
       .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I was trying  .Include(e1 => e1.Enderecos.Select(cep => cep.Cidade.UF))

Answer (score 0):

"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."

You are getting this because `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` is being called on the `DbQuery` after your `DbContext.Dispose` has been called.

The typical reason for this occuring in `ASP.Net MVC` is the following code.

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using(var database = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            var query = from x in database.Foos
                        ...blah blah blah...
                        select x;
            return View(query);
        }
    }
}
```

This is subtitle. But by the time the view runs `@foreach(var item in Model)` (which implicitely calls `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` your `Controller.Index()` method has already returned, and hence your database context has been disposed.

There are two ways to fix this.

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using(var database = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            var query = from x in database.Foos
                        ...blah blah blah...
                        select x;
            return View(query.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

This method ensures that we run `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` whilst the `DbContext` is still active. However I prefer the next method...

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private DatabaseContext _database = new DatabaseContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var query = from x in database.Foos
                    ...blah blah blah...
                    select x;
        return View(query);         
    }

    public override Dispose()
    {
        _database.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The reason being is that you can then add `.AsStreaming()` and `.AsNoTracking()` to your query. This means that your POCO objects live only long enough to be written by the View, reducing your memory load.

Answer (score 0):

**The Answer is in the question itself**

```
How can I Include Multiples Tables??
```

Just us **`INCLUDE`**, the Answer has already been pretty much explained by **Scartag**