# how write viewmodel to show 2 tables in one view and join between they

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm very very new in MVC 5 and I want to implement some pages like this Photo
[my Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGkl5.jpg)

I have a Bootstrap Carousel slider in Index view that get their images from DB , and I want display ( using Linq ) Good table in Index view then when click on each record redirect to another page and show ProductInfo,
thanks a lot ,

### sorry for my bad English :/

I create 3 Viewmodels like Shyju said :

```
public class GoodVM
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}

public class ProductImageVm
{
    public string Image { set; get; }
    public string Color { set; get; } 
}

public class ProductInfoVm
{
    public string ProductText { set; get; }
    public List<ProductImageVm> Images { set; get; } 
}
```

and I create a viewModel Like M.Azad said :

```
public class MyGoodVM
{
    public List<GoodVM> Goods { get; set;}
    public List<ProductInfoVm> ProductInfoes { get; set; }
    public List<ProductImageVm> ProductImages { get; set; }
}
```

and I Don't know how use these in Controller. I use Hadee code :
`var cliente = context.Goods 
   .Include(e => e.ProductInfoes)
   .Include(e1 => e1.Enderecos.ProductImages)
   .SingleOrDefault();`

but I don't know waht is "Include"? and still my problem not solved

Comment: How does your tables look ?

Comment: You need to show what you've done so far...

Comment: I inserted an image of my tables in my post

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vGkl5.jpg

Comment: you must search about navigation property in entityframework to find out about Include()

Answer (score 0):

You can have a viewmodel like this

```
public class MyViewModel
{
public List<Good> Goods { get; set;}
public List<ProductInfo> ProductInfoes { get; set; }
Public List<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
}
```

For more information chech this [MVC ViewModel](http://www.dotnettips.info/post/1243/%D9%86%D8%AD%D9%88%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2-viewmodel-%D8%AF%D8%B1-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Create viewmodels for your views.

```
public class GoodVm
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}

public class ProductVm
{
    public string ProductText { set; get; }    
    public List<ProductImageVm> Images { set; get; }                 
}
public class ProductImageVm
{
    public string Image { set; get; }
    public string Color { set; get; }    
}
```

For your index view, you need to get all the Goods

```
public ActionResult Goods()
{
  var vm = GetGoods();
  return View(vm);
}
private List<GoodVm> GetGoods()
{    
  return db.Goods.Select(s=> new GoodVm { Id = s.GoodID, Name = s.GoodName}).toList();
}
```

Your index view will be bound to a list of GoodVM

```
@model List<GoodVm>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <h2>@item</h2>
  @Html.ActionLink("view","View","Product",new {id=item.Id},null)
}
```

And for your ProductInfo page, Accept a good Id and use that to query the ProductInfo table

```
 public ActionResult View(int id)
 {
   var productVmList=GetProducts(id);
   return View(productVmList);
 }

 private List<ProductVm> GetProducts(int goodId)
 {
   return db.ProductInfos.Where(h=>h.Id==goodId)
              .Select(s => new ProductVm
               {
                 ProductText = s.InfoText,
                 Images = s.ProductImages.Select(c => new ProductImageVm
                 {
                   Color = c.Color,
                   Image = c.Image
                }).ToList()
             });
 }
```

And your view will be bound to  a list of `ProductVm`

```
@model List<ProductVm>
@foreach(var p in Model)
{
  <h2>@p.ProductText</h2>
  foreach(var img in p.Images)
  {
    <h3>@img.Color</h3>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much , I write your code but happened an error  on : 
private List<GoodVm> GetGoods()
on  GoodVm, GoodVm could not be found ..

Comment: Did you create those viewmodel classes ?

Comment: Yes I do, I create all of them , but VS says could not be found or missing assembly references

Comment: You need to make sure that you have the proper using statements to import the namespace where you created them, Also if you created in a different project, you need to add them as a project reference.

Comment: No I created them in the same project ,excuse me, what Namespaces need for this codes ?

Comment: Namespaces of your viewmodel if you defined them inside one.

Comment: I wrote " using MyAppName.Models;" but I got the same Error

Comment: Your question was about bringing data from multiple tables to a view and hence my answer for that. I am not quite sure about your classes/namespaces. My recommendation is to comment out all the new code and try to create an object of the new VM class and see whether you can fix the compilation error.

Comment: Thanks @MIKE , I forgotten "using AppName.ViewModels;" , I add this and this problem solved , but another error occur :/

Comment: In your view change (at sign cant type it here)model List<GoodVm> 
to (at sign cant type it here)model IEnumerable<AppName.ViewModels.GoodVm>

Comment: thank you , but Now my problem is with   :      Images = s.ProductImage.Select(c => new ProductImageVm
                           {
                               Color = c.Color,
                               Image = c.Image
                           }).ToList()

Answer (score 0):

Use M.Azad view model. Then in controller for index method, write your code somthing like ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671768/how-can-i-include-multiples-tables-in-my-linq-to-entities-eager-loading-using-mv)):

```
var cliente = context.Goods 
   .Include(e => e.ProductInfoes)
   .Include(e1 => e1.Enderecos.ProductImages)
   .SingleOrDefault();
```

So you will have your related objects in view. To show your tables, its' better to use Bootstrap modal ([here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)). Using modal helps you keep in the same view without need to transfer objects between views.

Comment: Thanks , I created 3 models for Good, ProductInfo and ProductImage , and I create a viewModel Like @M.Azad Said . But I don't understand how to use these in Linq query

Comment: Use the query like above!